# Group array of arrays and select some column in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this array of arrays:

```
    [[F1,State1,Blah1],[F2,State1,Blah2],[F1,State2,Blah3]]
```

Whats a neat ruby way to convert the above to:

```
    {State1=>[F1,F2],State2=>[F1]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-pass solution with [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
array.inject({}) { | a, (v, k, _) | a[k] ||= []; a.update(k => a[k] << v) }
```

Or a bit cleaner:

```
array.inject(Hash.new { | h, k | h[k] = [] }) { | a, (v, k, _) | a.update(k => a[k] << v) }
```

This is the functional way of writing:

```
result = {}
array.each do | v, k, _ | 
  result[k] = [] unless result.has_key? k
  result[k] << v
end
```

If you encounter performance issues, the `update` should be avoided:

```
array.inject({}) { | a, (v, k, _) | a[k] ||= []; a[k] << v; a }
```

For completeness, there is also [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which is a bit more suitable here:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { | (v, k, _), a | a[k] ||= [];  a[k] << v }
```

Comment: The elaborate way of writing this should have the same performance as inject I think?

Comment: @Vivek: I thought so. Testing it, the `inject` version is significantly slower. It's due to the `update`.

Comment: Thanks for the performance test. By the way I didn't understand that syntax - a.update(k => a[k] << v). What is this doing exactly?

Comment: It looks up the hash (`a[k]`), then it adds the new value to the result (`<< v`), then it creates a new hash consisting of just the one key and the array. Then it merges this hash into `a` thus updating `a[k]`. It's clear that this introduces overhead. The goal is to avoid the ugly "`; a`" at tthe end. `each_with_object` is better.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [['F1','State1','Blah1'],['F2','State1','Blah2'],['F1','State2','Blah3']]

arr.group_by{|a| a[1]}.map {|k,v| [k, v.map(&:first)] }.to_h
# => {"State1"=>["F1", "F2"], "State2"=>["F1"]}
```

Comment: This will be two passes over the array.

Comment: @Vivek But it's still `O(n)`, right? Except in performance-critical situations or situations where the performance gap between two solutions is particularly wide, I prefer to optimize for readability.

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present In both hashes being merged:

```
arr = [['F1','State1','Blah1'],['F2','State1','Blah2'],['F1','State2','Blah3']]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |(v,k,_),h| h.update(k=>[v]) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } }
 #=> { "State1"=>["F1","F2"],"State2"=>["F1"] }
```